# What is a simplistic definition of Boethius' Consolation with Philosophy?

Tags: theology, free-will, greeks, omniscience

The specific extract is where he asks Lady Philosophy about the correlation of omniscience and free will having a coherent existence together. I know the extract well, but I struggle to define it simplistically without writing about two pages. 
And if there is any additional information on it, that would be amazing.

Comment: Here is a [commentary](http://organizations.uncfsu.edu/ncrsa/journal/v05/rich_boethius.htm) that sketches Lady Philosophy's reply. SEP has a one paragraph summary of the ["Boethian solution"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/free-will-foreknowledge/#BoetSolu).